# Permissions to create and run stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, command-line, mysql-workbench

I want to create a user in Mysql and I want that user to have permissions to create and run stored procedure. I using mysql workbench. Can you please guide me how to create user from workbench or through command-line with stored procedure permission.
Workbench gives various options for permission as shown in below image, which options must be selected for have permission to create and run SP

[image]

Comment: I feel SQLyog is easy for user management.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this commands:

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'; 
GRANT ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE ROUTINE, EXECUTE ON *.* TO 'username'@'localhost' ;
```

Comment: I want to create stored procedures with in my master/super user, and execute/run it from another user, which is called by my web application. Is it possible? How do we do this?